# How to add tags in craft CMS 3

Tags: craft3, categories, tags

This is my first template that im working on in craft cms3, i've managed to make the most of the homepage and other tabs of website dynamic using the CMS, but I can't figure out how do I make tags and categories dynamic on the homepage and sidebars of all the related pages.

**The bottom of homepage which I want to make dynamic**

[image: the part whicih I want to make dyanmic on homepage]

**The sidebar of the page that I want to make dynamic**

[image: these are the sidebars which]

if you want to have a look at the website im working on heres the server link http://52.65.202.173/

Will be really grateful for the help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some basics:

First, tags and categories are two different things. As a first step, think long and hard about how you want to organize your content. Keep in mind that Categories can be hierarchical, whereas Tags are not.

To start using Categories, you must first create a Category set, say, "Blog", then specify categories within that set, e.g. Beauty, Health, etc. Note that you can assign fields to a category set, so you can associate things like icons or brief description for each one!

To use your Categories in entries, first create a Category field(s) and then add it to one or more of your channel entry types. then, when you create a new entry, you can assign a category to it.

To access entries by category in your templates, refer to [this section of Craft Docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/category-queries.html#example)